# Python inheritance with super

Tags: python, inheritance

I have two files each of them holding distinct classes. The code for my first class is the following:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def printInfo(self):
        print self.x,",",self.y
```

now I have a class Pixel that inherits from Point:

```
from fileA import Point

class Pixel(Point):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        #Point.__init__(self,x,y)     //works just fine
        super(Pixel,self).__init__()
        self.color=color

    def printInfo(self):
        super(Pixel,self).printInfo()
        print self.color
```

So as you can see Pixel inherits from Point, and it overrides the method printInfo. I have two problems here, first in the constructor of Pixel the line that is commented works fine, but the version with super throws an error. Also when I want to call from the printInfo method to the printInfo of the base class it throws another error. The question that I have is how can I use super in both, constructor and overrided method, so that it works?

I am using Python 2.7 and the error is TypeError: must be type, not classobj

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can only use `super` with new-style classes, but `Point` is currently an old-style class. To make it a new-style class, it must inherit from `object`:

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def getX(self):
        return self.x

    def printInfo(self):
        print self.x,",",self.y
```

Second, you have to pass the arguments that `Point.__init__` expects when you call it with `super`, just like you do using `Point.__init__(self,...)` directly:

```
class Pixel(Point):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        super(Pixel,self).__init__(x, y)  # Don't forget x,y
        self.color=color

    def printInfo(self):
        super(Pixel,self).printInfo()
        print self.color
```

Comment: thanks @dano, one last question why in the class Pixel why should I put in the super a call to itself, I mean super(Pixel,..)?

Comment: `super` works by searching for the method you want to call in the classes listed in the `__mro__` attribute of the type you pass as the first argument to `super`. So, if you want to find the `printInfo` method for `Pixel`, you would want to pass `Pixel` as the argument. You can read more about how it works [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super). Note that in Python 3.x, `super` has been enhanced so that you can simply call `super().printInfo()`/`super().__init__(self, x, y)` in this case. But since you're using Python 2.x, you have to use the longer version.